# Get error in installation of kazoo bigcouch

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to install kazoo-Bigcouch on CentOS 7, I am getting the following problem. Any solution?

```
● kazoo-bigcouch.service - BigCouch DB Configured for Kazoo
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kazoo-bigcouch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-08-17 05:17:28 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 10556 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/kazoo-bigcouch stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10576 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/kazoo-bigcouch background (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10565 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/kazoo-bigcouch prepare (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/kazoo-bigcouch.service
           └─10596 /opt/bigcouch/erts-5.9.3/bin/epmd -daemon

Aug 17 05:17:28 plsl01 systemd[1]: Starting BigCouch DB Configured for Kazoo...
Aug 17 05:17:28 plsl01 systemd[1]: Started BigCouch DB Configured for Kazoo.
```

If I check big-couch status, it gives
BigCouch is not running!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I solve problem by changing hostname .
 kazoo-bigcouch status
BigCouch (pid 1779) is running...
{"all_nodes":["bigcouch@aio.kazoo.com"],"cluster_nodes":["bigcouch@aio.kazoo.com"]}